# In mobile theme popup doesn't hide when we click outside popup

Tags: jquery-ui, magento, jquery-mobile, magento-1.7

I am using jquery.blockUI.js to show a popup for mobile application. Popup is shown when I click on button. But when I try to hide that popup on clicking outside that popup then it does not hide.

I am using this code to hide popup:-

```
jQuery('.blockOverlay').attr('title','Click to unblock').click(jQuery.unblockUI);
```

It works perfectly in desktop version of magento but Doesn't work for mobile theme.

Please help me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
function togglePopup(){
  var selector = '#popup',
    $popup = $(selector),
    callback = function(e) {
      if (!$(e.target).parents().andSelf().is(selector)) {
        $popup.hide();
        $(document).off('click', callback);
      }
    };

  $popup.toggle();
  if ($popup.is(':visible')) {
    $(document).on('click', callback);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: R u using JQuery Mobile or not??

Comment: No I am using simple  jquery.blockUI.js